# Android: get system colour palette programmatically

Tags: android

On Android devices the user can set up their phone with a particular colour palette, for styling the various system UI elements.  I'm sure this will differ from device to device, but here is an example:

[image]

Is it possible to query what these colours are programmatically from our code, at least just the primary and secondary colours or similar, so that we can make some of our own UI elements blend more seamlessly with the user's colour preferences from their system setup?  For example we could use the blue/light/dark colours from the palette selected in the example above, and use them in our app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Resources.getSystem().getColor() method to get system colors.

eg.
Resources.getSystem().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark)

Comment: Aren't these still just internal colour resources, not actually system colour resources like the colour used for the WiFi etc toggle buttons you see when you swipe down from the top on your phone?

Comment: I haven't used it in any of my apps, but according to the developer android docs it says "Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc), and is not affected by Runtime Resource Overlay".

Comment: For more details please visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getSystem()

Answer (score 0):

Material Design 3 is what [lets apps use colours generated from wallpaper](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/dynamic-color/user-generated-color) and themes the system colours and the like. I don't know much about it, and from a quick look around info on interacting with the themes programmatically is thin on the ground right now. I'm just pointing you in that general direction if you want to look into it!

Aside from that, you could do it manually - use [`WallpaperManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager) and one of the various `getDrawable` methods to grab the current wallpaper, and use the [Palette](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/palette) Jetpack library to [generate a `Palette` from the wallpaper's bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette)

(I noticed `WallpaperManager` lets you set a listener for when the wallpaper's colours change - wouldn't be surprised if the Material Design 3 stuff hooks into that to update its theme colours)

Comment: Basing a colour palette off the user's chosen wallpaper looks interesting!  I'm wondering more whether it's possible to query colours used for specific system UI elements, like the WiFi etc toggle buttons you see when you swipe down from the top... in my screenshot that's a blue colour, as per the selected palette in that setting screen... is it possible to grab that colour specifically, to use in our own app colour palette?

Comment: @drmrbrewer ohhh sorry, I kinda skimmed and saw the "choose from your wallpaper" palette options on the screenshot! I'm not sure about the UI stuff - that's gonna depend on the device and its customisations running on top of Android I think. Where's your screenshot from? But as far as I know there's no way to query that, I'm not an expert on the newer features though - but if it's not a feature of stock Android, you probably can't rely on being able to access that info

Comment: no, it's useful asking one question, expecting a certain type of answer, and then getting a different type of answer which leads you in a different direction... I'll look into the material design 3 stuff... you ask "Where's your screenshot from?"... it's from System settings > Wallpaper and style > Colour palette.

Comment: @drmrbrewer oh I mean, it's not stock Android 12 - is it from 13, or a non-Pixel device with a customisable UI? If it's the latter, those aren't necessarily gonna work the same way as each other, or using the same system that Material You uses in Android 12 (which is obviously only available in 12 - I think 10 was the first version that enabled *some kind* of colour theming through Developer Options). Without a single, consistent API to get these system colours, you might have a big job trying to get it working generally! I'd definitely explore what Vishesh is suggesting - you never know